# How to get user by it's objectGUID from Active Directory by using Novell.Directory.Ldap.NETstandard?

Tags: active-directory, ldap

I am writing a .NET Core application. The application is using "Novell.Directory.Ldap.NETStandard" v3.6.0 to connect with Active Directory on Windows. I am trying to fetch an entry using objectGUID but there is no base search available which means I need to search in the whole directory. Below is the code sample i am using.

```
string ldapHost = "ldap.example.com";
int ldapPort = 389;
string ldapUser = "cn=admin,dc=example,dc=com";
string ldapPassword = "password";

string searchBase = ""; // Set to null/empty to search from the root

string[] _attributes = { "objectGUID", "objectCategory", "objectClass" };

// Construct the search filter with the objectGUID attribute and the GUID value
string searchFilter = "(objectGUID=3EBCE0D7-89A1-41A5-9AFD-71C2A8BEC408)";

LdapConnection ldapConnection = new LdapConnection();
ldapConnection.Connect(ldapHost, ldapPort);
ldapConnection.Bind(ldapUser, ldapPassword);

LdapSearchConstraints searchConstraints = new LdapSearchConstraints();
searchConstraints.ReferralFollowing = true;

LdapSearchResults searchResults;
try
{
    searchResults = (LdapSearchResults)ldapConnection.Search(
            searchBase,
                LdapConnection.ScopeSub,
                    searchFilter,
                        _attributes,
                            false,
                                searchConstraints);
}
catch (LdapException ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Search operation failed: " + ex.Message);
    ldapConnection.Disconnect();
    return;
}

if (searchResults.HasMore())
{
    LdapEntry entry = searchResults.Next();
    string distinguishedName = entry.Dn;
    Console.WriteLine("Entry Found: " + distinguishedName);
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("Entry not found.");
}

ldapConnection.Disconnect();
```

Please note the `searchBase` is passed with `string.Empty` to search in the whole directory. When the code runs the connection establishes fine and gets below exception on `searchResults.Next()`

> 'No Such Object'

Please help me to find an entry from an active directory by using objectGUID where no search base is available.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Active Directory allows you to [bind directly to an object by the GUID](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/ad/using-objectguid-to-bind-to-an-object) using this format: `<GUID=XXXXX>`

So I believe you can set the search base to that and set the search scope to `ScopeBase`, like this:

```
searchResults = (LdapSearchResults)ldapConnection.Search(
        "<GUID=3EBCE0D7-89A1-41A5-9AFD-71C2A8BEC408>",
        LdapConnection.ScopeBase,
        "",
        _attributes,
        false,
        searchConstraints);
```

I've only done this with Microsoft's `DirectoryEntry` - I have no experience with the Novell library, so this might need some tweaks to get it to work.

Comment: I have also used it in DirectoryEntry but it doesn't work in Novell library this way.

Comment: Do you get an error message?

Comment: Yes when the searchBase is empty it gives 'No Such Object' error but when for testing purpose I set the this with a valid value I can search by distinguishedName but as soon as I try to search with objectGUID I get 'Operation Error'.

Comment: Oh, that's your issue. Set the search base to the guid and the filter to an empty string. By your description is sounds like you have it the other way around. I just tried this in my environment with the Novell library and it works.

Comment: Hey @Gabriel i tried as you said now i am getting 'Invalid DN Syntax' error. Can you please share me the code runs on your environment?

Comment: My code is exactly your code with the search line replaced with what I put in my answer (except I'm using a GUID that exists in my environment). Make sure the search base is in the format `"<GUID=XXX>"` where `XXX` is the GUID. You need the `<GUID=  >` parts.